# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Configure Unit Tests for UWP Project

Tags: azure, unit-testing, uwp, devops, pipeline

I'm pretty new to Azure DevOps and I am trying to get it to run the Unit tests (MSTest) as part of the pipeline. I'm using the default generated yaml for UWP. According to the documentation for unit tests I should have something like:

```
- task: VSTest@1
  displayName: Unit tests
  inputs:
    testAssembly: '**/*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

This is a high level of the file structure in question (relative to the yaml file):

```
Pipeline.yml
Project (folder)
  Project.sln
  ProjectDatabase (folder)
    bin (folder)
    obj (folder)
    ProjectDatabase.csproj
  ProjectDatabase.Test (folder)
    bin (folder)
    obj (folder)
    ProjectDatabase.Text.csproj
  ProjectDataAccess (folder)
    bin (folder)
    obj (folder)
    ProjectDataAccess.csproj
  ProjectDataAccess.Test (folder)
    bin (folder)
    obj (folder)
    ProjectDataAccess.Test.csproj
```

Each time I've tried varying the path but running the Pipeline just returns:
`##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**/**/*test*.dll;-:**\**\obj\**'.`

Am I even going down the right path and if so, am I missing something? Thanks in advance and I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: After doing more research, the first issue is that I need to not look for dll's but the appxrecipe files in the unit test solutions. I have done that but the issue I'm running into now is that when this is built, there's no bin folder or anything so I don't have the required appxrecipe files.

Answer (score 0):

I was not thinking and ran the Unit Tests separately from the build itself so the appxrecipe files were not present.

To have the tests run I had to use:

```
  -  task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Unit Tests
  inputs:
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    testSelector: 'TestAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: | # Required when testSelector == TestAssemblies
        **\Release\ProjectName.UWP.Test.build.appxrecipe
        **\Release\ProjectName.DataAccessUWP.Test.build.appxrecipe
        **\Release\ProjectName.DataUWP.Test.build.appxrecipe
        !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        !**obj** 
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    resultsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)TestResults'
```